# Oncomm event is fired occasionally

Tags: at-command, mscomm32

I'm trying to read incoming SMS

RThreshold value is set to 1

The Meassage Storage Area is "SM"

However, OnComm event is fired only when I send a command (e.g MSComm1.Output = "AT" & vcCrLf).. OnComm is fired when "OK" is returned

Why OnComm event is not fired when an incoming SMS is received?

Thank you.

```
Private Sub MSComm1_OnComm()
    If MSComm1.CommEvent = comEvReceive Then
        Beep
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add all the relevant code to the question. As it is now the question barely contains more information than "My car does not start but it started yesterday. The gasoline tank is not empty. What could it be?".

Comment: Did my code really help? @hlovdal

Comment: The keywords here are "**all** the **relevant** code". Your `MSComm1_OnComm` functions is absolutely relevant, but it is far, far away from representing the whole issue. You say "OnComm is fired when ..." but you do not include any code that shows this binding/connection. You need to include that in the question for instance (and not only just that. **All** relevant code).

Comment: Do you even know what does OnComm event mean?!